# How do I get from my local repository to a full clone?

Tags: git, git-clone

If I am starting from scratch I can clone a remote git repository using the command

```
git clone --mirror <repository-url>
```

([Documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone).)

However I am not starting from scratch, I already have several branches locally (tracking the remote): all the ones I made and the branch called 'master'.

How do I get from this 'partial clone' to a full clone? I could list all the branches and tags on the remote repository and fetch them one by one, but is there a command like `git clone` that will catch my local repository up with the remote one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I get from this 'partial clone' to a full clone

What you are lookiing for is called [fetch](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch)

```
# update my local repo with all the data from the remote server 
git fetch --all --prune
```

[image]

Comment: This does not seem to work for me. `git branch` shows I have two local branches, while `git ls-remote` lists sixteen branches. After I run `git fetch --all --prune` if I rerun `git branch` I still only see two branches.

Comment: type: `git branch -a` which stands for all. without the `-a` you only print your local branches